# What file format could this password safe file be in?

Tags: file-format

I found a file named `passwords.passsafe` in an old backup of mine, with a timestamp from July 2000. I'm not 100% sure I remember the password. I have unsuccessfully tried to decrypt it using Password Safe (v1.12 by Rony Shapiro, installed from an Ubuntu repository). This program won't tell me whether the file is valid or not - it will let me try any password against any file.

Although the filename extension strongly suggests this is a Password Safe file, I cannot be sure, and the file format doesn't conform to any of the [specifications here](https://github.com/pwsafe/pwsafe/tree/master/docs).

The first two lines of the file are:

```
THIS FILE CONTAINS ENCRYPTED DATA - DO NOT MODIFY
1.5
```

These lines are followed by CRLF-delimited lines of random-looking ASCII characters.

I note that July 2000 predates the release of the first open source version of Password Safe. It's possible that I used Bruce Schneier's original closed-source release, though I cannot find any information on the file format that version used, nor a copy of the executable.

Comment: There is a [CVE on Password Safe 1.7 by Counterpane](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2001-0984), the company Bruce Schneier was involved in. The CVS is dated dated 2001-09-13. So a file from 2000 that contains a reference to v1.5 is reasonable.